# modifying :before of an element when hovered is not working

Tags: html, css

I simply want the `:before` (underline) of my anchor to change its height every time it is hovered over, but it's not working.

I hope someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

```css
.wrapper {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

a {
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 font: 4em Arial;
 color: #21a1e1;
 font-weight: 300;
 position: relative;
}

a:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 bottom: 0;
 background: #21a1e1;
 transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}


/* not working */
a:hover a:before {
 height: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <a href="">Hover</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **a:hover::before** instead of **a:hover a:before** I'm added the working snippet below.

```css
.wrapper {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

a {
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 font: 4em Arial;
 color: #21a1e1;
 font-weight: 300;
 position: relative;
}

a:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 bottom: 0;
 background: #21a1e1;
 transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}


/* not working */
a:hover::before {
 height: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <a href="">Hover</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Great help. Thanks a lot